# May i know what is wrong with my phpcode?

Tags: php

This is what i have for headers.php anyway it is suppose to be my navigation bar. Here's the problem, when I login with a user as Member the whole header does not come out. But when I login with admin the navigations will "magically" come out!

```
    <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['sRole'])){
        ?>
            <div id="header">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
                 <div id ="inthebox">
                        <a href="login.php" class="link"><b>LOGIN</b></a>|
                        <a href="register.php" class="link"><b>REGISTER</b></a>
                </div>  
                        <div id ="outthebox">
                            <a href="index.php" class="link">HOME</a>|
                            <a href="bookshelf.php" class="link">BOOKSHELF</a>|
                            <a href="shoppingcart.php" class="link">SHOPPING CART</a>|
                            <a href="about.php" class="link">ABOUT</a>|
                                                <a href="logout.php" class="link">ABOUT</a>|

                        </div>




            </div>

        <?php
        }
        else{

                if($_SESSION['sRole'] == "member"){
        ?>
        <div id="header">
                                <div id ="inthebox">
                        <a href="logout.php" class="link"><b>LOGOUT</b></a>
                                        </div>

                                     <div id ="outthebox">
                            <a href="index.php" class="link">HOME</a>|
                            <a href="bookshelf.php" class="link">BOOKSHELF</a>|
                            <a href="shoppingcart.php" class="link">SHOPPING CART</a>|
                            <a href="about.php" class="link">ABOUT</a>|
                                                <a href="updateProfile.php" class="link">PROFILE</a>
                            <?php
                                echo("You have Login as :" . $_SESSION['sUsername']);
                            ?>
                        </div> 





            </div>
        <?php
            }else{
                if($_SESSION['sRole']=="admin"){
                    ?>
            <div id="header">
                    <div id ="inthebox">
                    <a href="logout.php" class="link"><b>LOGOUT</b></a>
                        </div>
                    <div id="outthebox">
                            <a href="index.php" class="link">HOME</a>|
                            <a href="bookshelf.php" class="link">BOOKSHELF</a>|
                            <a href="shoppingcart.php" class="link">SHOPPING CART</a>|
                            <a href="about.php" class="link">ABOUT</a>|
                                                <a href="account.php" class="link">Manage Account</a>|
                                                <a href="managebook.php" class="link">Manage Books</a>|
                                                <a href="manageOrder.php" class="link">Manage Orders</a>|
                            <?php
                                echo("You have Login as :" . $_SESSION['sUsername']);
                            ?>
                        </div> 




            </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }   
        ?>
```

This is my doLogin.php page , maybe it might help anyone here to solve this. I store the id, username, firstname and last name into the session. Inside have alr . The website hor when I go in is no error one . no html code error or whatsoever. Just that it does not appear. However the words below the nav links will still come out.

```
    <?php
     //connect to database
    include ('dbfunction.php'); 
    if (!isset($_POST['Login'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
            //retrieve form data
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'AND password = '" . $password . "'";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die('The error :' . mysql_error());
            $num_rows =mysql_num_rows($result);

            if($num_rows == 0){
                 header('Location:login.php');
                exit();
                }
            //if record is found, store id and username into session
            else{
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $_SESSION['sUsername'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['sRole'] = $row['role'];
                $_SESSION['sFirst_name'] = $row['first_name'];
                $_SESSION['sLast_name'] = $row['last_name'];

                header('location:successful_login.php');//redirect to this page
                exit();
            } 
        }
            else { 


            }
    } else {
            header('Location:successful_login.php');
            exit();
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: that is what the script is supposed to do, ain't it? Display different output based on user role. In case of user, it won't show Manage Account, Manage Books links

Comment: You should read about `else if` statements.

Comment: check the code where you have created the session..
post the codes here.. let us check. This is how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you are using `} else {` conditions, but then nesting an `if` statement inside of them. In fact it looks like you had some broken closing braces. Here is the revised code:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['sRole'])){ ?>
    <div id="header">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
         <div id ="inthebox">
                <a href="login.php" class="link"><b>LOGIN</b></a>|
                <a href="register.php" class="link"><b>REGISTER</b></a>
        </div>  
                <div id ="outthebox">
                    <a href="index.php" class="link">HOME</a>|
                    <a href="bookshelf.php" class="link">BOOKSHELF</a>|
                    <a href="shoppingcart.php" class="link">SHOPPING CART</a>|
                    <a href="about.php" class="link">ABOUT</a>|
                                        <a href="logout.php" class="link">ABOUT</a>|

                </div>




    </div>

<?php } else if($_SESSION['sRole'] == "member") { ?>

<div id="header">
                        <div id ="inthebox">
                <a href="logout.php" class="link"><b>LOGOUT</b></a>
                                </div>

                             <div id ="outthebox">
                    <a href="index.php" class="link">HOME</a>|
                    <a href="bookshelf.php" class="link">BOOKSHELF</a>|
                    <a href="shoppingcart.php" class="link">SHOPPING CART</a>|
                    <a href="about.php" class="link">ABOUT</a>|
                                        <a href="updateProfile.php" class="link">PROFILE</a>
                    <?php
                        echo("You have Login as :" . $_SESSION['sUsername']);
                    ?>
                </div> 





    </div>

<?php }else if($_SESSION['sRole']=="admin"){ ?>

    <div id="header">
            <div id ="inthebox">
            <a href="logout.php" class="link"><b>LOGOUT</b></a>
                </div>
            <div id="outthebox">
                    <a href="index.php" class="link">HOME</a>|
                    <a href="bookshelf.php" class="link">BOOKSHELF</a>|
                    <a href="shoppingcart.php" class="link">SHOPPING CART</a>|
                    <a href="about.php" class="link">ABOUT</a>|
                                        <a href="account.php" class="link">Manage Account</a>|
                                        <a href="managebook.php" class="link">Manage Books</a>|
                                        <a href="manageOrder.php" class="link">Manage Orders</a>|
                    <?php
                        echo("You have Login as :" . $_SESSION['sUsername']);
                    ?>
                </div> 




    </div>
            <?php
}
```

Comment: I tried using the code u posted above on my web, But its still the same result. yea But it still works for admin tho.

Comment: which is which part ??

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php if( (!isset($_SESSION['sRole'])) || (empty($_SESSION['sRole'])) || (is_null($_SESSION['sRole'])) ): ?>
 <html>your code</html>
<?php else: ?>
      <?php switch($_SESSION['sRole']) {
            case 'admin': { // admin code } break;
            case 'member': { // member code } break;
            default: { // something happened } break;
       }
      ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

check and diagnose the issue